# Ansible: use group_vars directly without with_items

Tags: ansible

I have defined `group_vars` to mount nfs shares on numerous hosts based on their environment:

```
---
mounts:
- path: /home/user1
  src: 10.0.0.1:/home/user1
  fstype: nfs
  state: present
- path: /home/user2
  src: 10.0.0.1:/home/user2
  fstype: nfs
  state: present
```

In my playbook I have the following task to add those mounts:

```
---
- hosts: clients
  tasks:
  - name: mounts
    mount:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      src: "{{ item.src }}"
      fstype: "{{ item.fstype }}"
      opts: "{{ item.opts }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
    with_items: "{{ mounts }}"
```

Now I was wondering if there is a shorthand to achieve the same thing? E.g.

```
---
- hosts: clients
  tasks:
  - name: mounts
    mount: "{{ mounts }}"
```

Comment: Sure seems like that should work. Did you try it? Perhaps in `--check` mode if you are worried about breaking something?

Comment: Yes, with my example above the error is `"missing required arguments: state, path"`. Which is the same result if I use `mount` with `with_items: "{{ mounts }}"` or `with_list: "{{ mounts }}"` only.

Comment: which version of ansible are you on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module is not capable of making several mounts in a single call, so you will still have to go through each individual mount definition with a loop. But you can set all parameters in one go from your individual dicts.

Before I write the (easy) solution, you should still be warned that setting tasks arguments like this is [discouraged in ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe) because it can be unsafe in some circumstances. This is why you will get a warning when using the code below:

```
- hosts: clients
  tasks:
    - name: mounts
      mount: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ mounts }}"
```